# How do I paste into a selected folder using CTRL+V?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

When I CTRL+X to cut multiple files in Windows Explorer, I can right-click a destination directory and select "Paste" and those files will be pasted *into* that selected directory.

However, if I *select* that destination directory and press CTRL+V (to paste), the files instead go into the current directory, *not* the selected one.

What is the keyboard-equivalent method of pasting files *into* the selected directory in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Are you ctrl-v in the right pane of that selected folder in explorer? Or are you just highlighting the folder then ctrl-v

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "right pane of that selected folder". I am simply selecting the folder and pressing CTRL+V.

Answer (score 0):

Folders in Explorer's **tree view** can be <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> pasted into.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> cut a selected file.

[image]

<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> over into tree view.

[image]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> paste into selected destination.

[image]

Focus may either remain in tree view or switch back to file/node view.

Note that the "Expand to open folder" view option is helpful here.

[image]